# An answer and comments just disappear?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, deleted-comments

I've seen other Meta posts about answers and comments disappearing due to moderator intervention or by the author, but I'm surprised here -- I have a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508213/using-channels-with-paramiko), and (unless I'm just going crazy) had an answer and some very useful comments about when to use transports and channels, but it seems the question is now completely clean. No comments, no answers. Am I confused, or in this case was something deleted?

I've looked in my SO question history, and this was the only post about Paramiko I've posted. Since 10k rep is probably more than a few days away for me (hah), I'd like to know, because the answer and comments were helpful, but unfortunately I didn't take any notes outside of SO thinking they would be here. I also can't recall the user who make the comments either, just that there was a pretty clear explanation of why someone would want to use a Channel (which uses a Transport) rather than just execute an ssh command and capture the output.

**TL;DR;** Can someone see if the above linked question had answers that were deleted, and if so, explain why? (Along with the comments made, including my own?)

Comment: You did have an answer, but the owner of the answer deleted it on August 21.

Comment: fortunately my answer is still there. just undeleted it. personally i would periodically check answers i own and i would delete some which turn out not to be *useful*.

Comment: I appreciate it -- I'll definitely be sure to upvote it this time :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the question had an answer that was deleted by its author.

The answer was posted on August 4th, and remained visible until it was deleted on August 21st. It received no upvotes in that time, so the author very likely concluded it was not useful and removed it. Or maybe he had some other reason for removing it; we really wouldn't know without asking him.

When a post is deleted, the comments underneath disappear along with it.

So no, you are not going crazy.

Comment: That's too bad, because it was useful -- I guess I didn't realize that happened, that people deleted answers that didn't get adequate votes. Unless someone wants to send the text my way, I just lost some really useful stuff. Thanks for the response, I guess senility has not yet grasped my mind after all. (I also could have sworn I upvoted it as well.)

Comment: Lesson learned? Next time you find an answer useful, upvote it.

Comment: Could have sworn I did -- I'm not stingy with votes, but perhaps I was in a hurry or something.  Thanks.

Comment: _"So no, you are not going crazy."_ [Mandatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/552/).