# Deleted posts and their comments

Tags: support

This is more or less a sanity check for me.

With respect to *[Why is there an error while getting JSON information in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294327/why-is-there-an-error-while-getting-json-information-in-python)*,

1. I looked at the poster's profile and it shows that they posted only one question.
2. I could have sworn that I posted a comment on that topic. Another user had posted another comment before me.
3. Now when I looked at this post in the "First Post" review queue, I'm seeing just one comment.
4. I looked at my comments posts and I don't see *any* comments posted to that question.

In order to self-explain this phenomenon, I'm thinking that the following happened (and since I can't see deleted posts, I'm just speculating).

1. User posted a question.
2. One user posted a comment. I posted a second comment.
3. After a bit, the user deleted the question and posted the same/similar question as a new question.
4. Another user posted a comment.

Would this satisfactorily explain what I'm experiencing? (That or the [Mandela effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_memory#Manifestations_and_types).) Deleted posts also delete comments (which are then removed from my list of comments I've made).

Any clarifications are appreciated.

I have looked at [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_memory#Manifestations_and_types), but I am not sure if it is related.

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_memory#Manifestations_and_types) - [An answer and comments just disappear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355936/an-answer-and-comments-just-disappear)

Comment: Yes, what you're thinking is correct.

Comment: Thanks @BhargavRao.  I thought i was going crazy.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate as that question asks what to do with users posting again and again; while this question asks about the after effects.  But in any event, @BhargavRao clarified my issue.

Comment: Yep, I closed it as a duplicate, as that post informs about what to do with such users. I can reopen it... but I don't think it is necessary to reopen, as the answer would just be "yes, that's what happened" :)

Comment: @BhargavRao ah thanks.  No, don't bother reopening it.  :)

Comment: I [save a link to each comment I post](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Comment-History-Checker) to ensure I can see a clear history (including links to now-deleted questions) which can help in cases like these

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance!  that should help me keep my sanity :)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396474/8620333